# What to do if files content is the same and nothing else has been changed?

Tags: linux, windows, git, svn, smartgit

I'm working in a environment where files are at Windows side (because I like to work with phpStorm from that side) and Linux side (because I've a Virtual Machine running CentOS 6.6 and there is where LAMP environment is). The phpStorm project is a remote files one. This are the steps I followed to create the project:

- Clone the repo at Windows directory
- Copy the files to Linux using WinSCP
- Create the remote project using phpStorm and this step copy the whole files from Linux to Windows.

I'm using SmartGit to manage my repos and do GIT/SVN tasks (the easy way). But surprise, files hasn't been changed but SmartGit says it does, but waits? How is that possible if the only steps I did was the one described above? Even if you try to open a file SmartGit will said that the content is the same? So, how to avoid this behavior? How to not to commit the whole files? If I made a commit already, how do I dismiss it? Is not the first time I'm running this problem but before repos was mine and I can lose every but now is a serious project and I take care for not damage others work. Any advice? Help? What you can do in this case?

See this pic:

[image]

There you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: contents may be the same, but stuff like file timestamps MAY have changed.

Comment: Git doesn't care about timestamps, but permissions, or, depending on how everything is configured, line endings could have changed.